# Correct way to import a class from a package in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class like this in package `a`:

```
class A:

      @staticmethod
      def method(param1, param2):
          ...
          return something
```

And in a python file:

```
from a import A

print(A.A.method(p1,p2))
```

What is wrong in my definitions? I think isn't correct to call a static method by `Class.Class.method'.

Screenshots with errors:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you have put A twice.

Comment: Because I receive the error: AttributeError: module 'a.A' has no attribute 'method'

Comment: Your screenshot is different from you code.

Comment: Yes, because `A.A.method(p1,p2)` work and I said "I think isn't correct" and I show a way what I think is correct but doesn't work.

Comment: I tested in console and it's same. I use PyCharm with python 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT after question was updated with picture]

So your top-level app is called `a` you can see this in the picture just under "Information" on the left in the picture. Then you have a module called `A`, which you can see the file `A.py` just under the folder `a`. This `module A` has the `class` called `A`

[image]

so when you do `from a import A` you are importing the file `A.py`

That file has a `class A()` which has `def method(p1, p2)`

You say `A.A.method()` is working... and that would be **correct**

It now becomes

```
from a import A
print(A.A.method(p1,p2)
```

Alternatively

```
import a
print(a.A.A.method(p1,p2)
```

Or

```
from a.A import A
print(A.method(p1, p2)
```

> My advice: start using some more descriptive names, not `a` for `top
>   level package` and `A` for `module` and `A` for `class`

Comment: I understand and I tried this solution before asking, but doesn't work. And I don't now if is from me or from somethings is wrong with my python. I added 2 screenshots with errors.

Comment: Thanks for advice. In practice I have descriptives name but this was just for explain. And I understand what happens, thanks.  So, the correct order for what I want to do is `from package.file_name import class`. And now I understand better the imports in Python.